# Remove duplicated elements of a column list and make comparisons

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe where all columns are list of values (could be tuple if it facilitates the operation). The index "Name" is not a list, they are unique values in this data. Most of the lists have duplicated values:
[image]

```html
Name Department Business Unit Person Number Line Manager Name Line Manager Work Email Username Job Name Role vs Family
0 Betty [' Department', 'Department', 'Department'] ['Antarctica', 'Antarctica', 'Antarctica'] [10038253, 10038253, 10038253] [nan, nan, nan] [nan, nan, nan] ['betty@jane.com', 'betty@jane.com', 'betty@ja... [nan, nan, nan] ['Do not match', 'Do not match', 'Do not match']
1 Bob ['Other Department', 'Other Department'] ['Poland.', 'Poland'] [10036224, 10036224] ['Jane ', 'Jane '] ['jane@jane.com', 'jane@jane.com''] ['bob@jane.com', 'bob@jane.com'] [nan, nan] ['Do not match', 'Match']

Final data Frame would look like this


Name Department Business Unit Person Number Line Manager Name Line Manager Work Email Username Job Name Role vs Family
0 Betty Department Antarctica 10038253 NaN NaN betty@jane.com NaN Do not match
1 Bob Other Department Poland 10036224 Jane jane@jane.com bob@jane.com NaN ['Do not match', 'Match']
```

I need to do the following operations:

1- Remove all duplicated values inside each list;

2- Filter the dataframe checking if a column list contain an element (for example, filter all 'Business Units' that has 'Antarctica' on it as at least 1 of its elements);

3- Compare if an element inside a column list exists inside the other column list (for example, if one of the 'Line Manager Work Email' exists in one of the 'Username' element list).

Thank you so much for the support!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael just edited, is it better like this? Sorry and thank you!

Comment: Super, much better. Is possible create expected output DataFrame? Or this is last column in sample data?

Comment: @jezrael it is displayed the dataframe here in html, I created 2 sample rows that can be used to solve this. Is that what is needed?

Comment: I think sample data seems nice, but how looks final dataframe from this 2 rows of data after applying all your conditions? For easy verify my or another answerer solution

Comment: @jezrael like that? Thank you so much, now I understood how to do it :)

Comment: Exactly, check if match answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for remove duplicates in all columns without first by converting lists to sets - all values without missing values:

```
def f(x):
     L = list(set(y for y in x if pd.notna(y)))
     #if empty list return NaN
     if len(L) == 0:
         return np.nan
     #if one element list return scalar
     elif len(L) == 1:
         return L[0]
     #else return full list
     else:
         return L

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(f)
print (df)
    Name       Department BusinessUnit PersonNumber LineManagerName  \
0  Betty       Department   Antarctica     10038253             NaN   
1    Bob  OtherDepartment       Poland     10036224            Jane   

  LineManagerWorkEmail        Username JobName         RolevsFamily  
0                  NaN  betty@jane.com     NaN           Donotmatch  
1        jane@jane.com    bob@jane.com     NaN  [Donotmatch, Match]
```

Comment: Hello Jezrael, almost! The first thing I believe would be to check if inside the list there is any duplicate. It should not return the full list, it should return the full list without duplicates.

Comment: @PauloCortez - I ask for expected output, so not match?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake when pasting the data, but it works very well, thank you so much!!!!